# Form data cleared when press the browser back button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint-2010

I am using views concept in my asp.net form control.my first view consist of a form to capture user details.when user press continue it will move to the second view. The problem is ,When user press the back button of the browser,It does not keep state of the previously entered data.the form got cleared.

we cant use both viewsstates and Sessions for this since they got reset in the back button click,

Is there any solutions we can take to overcome this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using MVC, if there is a post happening between the first and the second view, you can store the data from the first view in the user's session on the server, which should not have been rest by a back button click. You can force the browser to reload the first form on back button navigation by setting the NoCache attribute on it. Then, just check to see if they have any existing form data in their session, and populate it when they request that action.